# Send dropdown value to backend using Angular and .Net Core

Tags: .net, angular, entity-framework, dropdown

My backend class looks like this :

```
public partial class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();
    }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

Between Books and Authors I have a many to many relationship, so BookAuthor is a join table. I am trying to send the data from angular to asp.net core, and in the create book page I have a dropdown with all the authors. My problem is that I cannot send the author picked in the dropdown, what I would like to accomplish would be to insert data in BookAuthor table as well when I create a book, but I cannot have the authorId.

In angular I have this :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

this.operation = this.route.snapshot.params['operation'];

this.authorService.getAuthors()
  .subscribe((authors: IAuthor[]) => {
    this.authors = authors,
      authors.forEach((author) => {
        this.authorsDropdown.options.push({ key: author.authorId, value: author.authorName });
      });
  });

if (this.operation === 'create') {
  this.book = {
    bookId: 0, title: '', authors: [], authorsDropdown: this.authorsDropdown 
  };
  console.log(this.book);
} else {
  this.bookService.getBook(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe((book: Book) => { this.book = book });
}
}
```

I can see my selected option in the authorsDropdown, but how can I send the authorId to the backend ? In the createBook in Angular I have this:

```
createBook(book: Book) {
book.bookId = 0;
for (let a of book.authors) {
  a.authorId = Number(this.authorsDropdown.key);
  book.authors.push(a);
} 
this.errorMessage = null;
this.bookService.createBook(book).subscribe(
  b => this.router.navigate(['/authenticated/book-maint']),
  err => this.errorMessage = 'Error creating book'
);
```

}

And in C# :

```
public Book Create([FromBody] Book book)
{
  // validation
  if (book == null)
  {
    throw new AppException("Book not found");
  }

  _context.Book.Add(book);
  _context.SaveChanges();

  var bookAuthor = new BookAuthor();
  bookAuthor.BookId = book.BookId;
  bookAuthor.AuthorId = ??

  return book;
}
```

I hope I managed to explain what I want to do. Thanks !

Comment: What is you're issue? You don't know how to send the data over http? or you're sending the data and it's not getting to the server?

Comment: I don't know how to take the authorId from the authorsDropdown and send it to the backend. What I tried in the createBook method is not working. In C# I receive a Book but it has BookAuthors empty. The for in createBook is not working...I was trying to put the authorsId in the book.authors but is not the correct approach apparently..

Comment: it’s really difficult to understand what the problem is when you haven’t included the code for sending.  But the easiest way to fix your problem is create a custom action to handle this.  Your book model expects the whole book author model not just the id.  So either send the full model, or create an action which will handle this on the c# end and call that directly

Comment: But BookAuthor has BookId and AuthorId, and this is why I'm trying to send the authorId as well, I already have the BookId, I need to take the AuthorId from the dropdown...the code for sending is in the createBook method in angular..how should I update that for so it takes the authorId from the dropdown ? I should create a bookAuthor entity in angular as well ?

Comment: I only see you call create book do you access http to send it?

Comment: Yes, this line (this.bookService.createBook(book).subscribe...) calls the createBook() from the BookService which uses http to post the book, the book creation is working..I just cannot pass that authorId from the dropdown so I can insert data into BookAuthor table as well.